# Spring boot - Oracle - Memory heap issue

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, heap-memory, hikaricp

We have a spring boot application that creates oracle connection using Hikari for connection pooling. It has 9 entities in total. The app is started using the following VM options: -Xmx250M -Xms10M. After starting the app, it is always reserving 101 MB heap memory as seen in Visual VM.

[image]

When a spring boot app is created with an oracle connection using spring data (in application properties without any programmed data source creation) it takes around 58 MB.

[image]

What heap memory is usually considered normal in springboot similar applications? also can an embedded tomcat server inside x spring boot apps use more heap memory than an x spring boot apps running on an external tomcat server?

Hikari config:

```
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................none
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
connectionTimeout...............6000000
dataSource......................none
dataSourceClassName.............none
dataSourceJNDI..................none
driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............none
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.20.0.8:1521/BBB
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................0
maximumPoolSize.................30
metricRegistry..................none
metricsTrackerFactory...........none
minimumIdle.....................5
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
scheduledExecutor...............none
schema..........................none
threadFactory...................internal
transactionIsolation............default
validationTimeout...............5000
```

Comment: From your description, I can't even tell if there's really an issue. Sure, your application might be taking 300MB of heap memory, but is that bad? Maybe it created a lot of objects that can now be cleaned up. But if you configured your heap size to be very huge, maybe the JVM decided that the GC shouldn't kick in yet. I would only start to worry when even after a GC the amount of heap memory stays high, or if it keeps going up. But none of that information is present in your question, so this is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: when we run multiple spring boots on the same machine, it adds 300 for each and when we start receiving api calls, it can increase more and more.. Is this situation usually considered normal in micro services architecture? and what is the memory heap that is considered normal if the app is not called?

Comment: This could be normal behaviour depending on how you configured your heap limit. But again, you still haven't included that information so this question remains unanswerable.

Comment: Without knowing your configuration, the amount of entities and/or database structure you have. This question will be impossible to answer. Is 300MB much could be, but depending on **your application** that might be not that much. There is no rule of thumb here.

Comment: Adjusted my question . Thank you

Comment: It makes sense that when you add a library that causes extra objects to be instantiated, that in return it causes extra memory to be used. Some of these objects will be stay around, and other objects were just temporarily created and can be removed from the heap. The thing with the JVM is that it doesn't always remove those immediately because removing those is an expensive operation. Very often, the JVM will wait until it is close to reaching the max heap, and then it will start removing those objects from the heap/garbage collect.

Comment: So the amount of memory consumed depends on a ton of factors, such as which JVM you use, which GC mode you use, whether you create a lot of objects, whether you use a lot of libraries that create a lot of objects, what your heap limit is and so on. All these factors make it so that there's no such thing as a standard amount of memory that a Spring boot application will use. It's very likely that if you reduce your `Xmx` even further, that the amount of memory your application will also go down, without any real problems (but that's for you to monitor).

Comment: Thank you for this helpful explanation, its clear now.